# Tikz Plot Small Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to change this code so that my dashed lines start at the first rectangle, like how they are at the second rectangle. Also, how can I delete the upward axis on the second rectangle?

Code:

```
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 %\draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0.1] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0) node[below left]{$$};
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X2) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,5}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
%       \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
%        {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,1);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: When making an MWE, please remember to keep it compilable: retain all the `usepackage` lines necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw an additional dashed line, you can add a line before the `foreach` loop :

```
\draw[densely dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
```

I am not sure which rectangle is the second. The axes are defined by the two `\draw[stealth-stealth]` commands.